# System.InvalidOperationException on Sample Code

Tags: vb.net, web, service, wsdl

I am using some existing sample code given to me from FedEx.com for tracking packages. However, I cannot get it to work for the life of me. Would anyone know what the following means:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message="Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1). error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert 
           type 'AddressValidationWebServiceClient.AddressValidationWebReference.ParsedElement' 
           to 'AddressValidationWebServiceClient.AddressValidationWebReference.ParsedElement[]' "
  Source="System.Xml"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)    
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)    
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)    
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GetSerializersFromCache(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)    
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)    
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientType..ctor(Type type)    
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol..ctor()    
       at AddressValidationWebServiceClient.AddressValidationWebReference.AddressValidationService..ctor() in C:\Documents and Settings\jessey\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddressValidationWebServiceClient\Web References\AddressValidationWebReference\Reference.vb:line 40    
       at AddressValidationWebServiceClient.AddressValidationWebServiceClient.Main() in C:\Documents and Settings\jessey\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddressValidationWebServiceClient\AddressValidationWebServiceClient.vb:line 28    
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)    
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()    
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)    
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

The offending line of code is:

`Dim service As AddressValidationService = New AddressValidationService()`

Comment: Is the offending line of code inside a method?

Comment: I think your sample is broken. Try to add the Service URL your self, to generate the proxy classes.

Comment: The offending piece is in the Sub Main() of the module.

Comment: dummy - They gave me the wsdl and sample code as is. How do I add the service URL?

Comment: I figured it out. See here : http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2010/02/01/error-cs0029-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-using-wsdl-tool/. But for vb.net replace all ()() with (). Thanks.